# Cannot fill down formulae in table downloaded from ODBC

Tags: vba, excel, odbc

I am importing data from a MySQL database through ODBC into Excel. Data is imported into Excel as a Table Object.

I then insert a set of formulae (with references to columns of the table) to the very last row of the imported table. I want these formulae to be filled down automatically when a brand new row is added to the table (this will save me a lot of time when it comes to exporting data back to my database).

But it's not happening - formulae would not get copied to new rows, no matter what settings I have tried.

Excel does not have any problems with auto inserting formulae when you add new rows to a simple table (i.e. not obtained from ODBC) - this is why I have decided to do it this way in the first place. However, things stop working. The problem is exacerbated by the fact that I do not think that it is possible to trigger VBA on changes to the table object itself (i.e. not the worksheet).

Any advice or help would be much appreciated

Comment: How are new rows being added to the table?  Manually or by refreshing the table from the ODBC data source?

Comment: They are added manually

Comment: I tested this with an Access table data connection and it worked as expected.  When I typed a new column header in the column immediately to the right of the Excel table, Excel automatically extended the table over it.  When I typed a formula (based on other columns) into the cell below that header and hit "enter", it automatically populated down the column (no copy/paste or dragging of the fill handle).  When I added a new row manually by typing in the left-most column just under the last row in the table, Excel extended the table downward to cover it and the formula populated.

Comment: Did any of the behavior I described above happen differently for you before the last part of the formula not populating?

Comment: The trouble is that I am not creating new columns - I am trying to add formulae "half-way" through the existing column. Doing it this way because I already have previously calculated values stored in my DB

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the best answer here is that Excel will not autopopulate, for new rows, a formula which is not assigned to the entire table column.  I suggest that you either create a new column in the table with the formula you need, or completely replace the existing column with the formula.